# Scroll snapping not working on windows and other devices

Tags: html, css

I have page with scroll snapping. It seems to be working fine on Mac but on some devices (specially windows) it becomes just scroll. And visitors have to put a lot of effort to read the content by figuring out where the content is as scroll snapping doesn't work.

What is a user friendly way to fix this?

```css
.rightside {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.snap1 {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.snap2 {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.snap3 {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 200vh;
}

.snap4 {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 300vh;
}

.snap5 {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 400vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="rightside">
  <div class="snap1">
    Page 1 : Hello world
  </div>
  <div class="snap2">
    Page 2 : Hello world
  </div>
  <div class="snap3">
    Page 3 : Hello world
  </div>
  <div class="snap4">
    Page 4 : Hello world
  </div>
  <div class="snap5">
    Page 5 : Hello world
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you try scrollIntoView()

Comment: Not sure how to use ScrollintoView()

Comment: it works on windows 10 Chrome perfectly fine. the only thing is why did you put margin-top for sections? there's no need for it

Answer (score 0):

The property:

```
scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
```

is not supported by older browsers, you might have to also add:

```
scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100vh);
```

It could be the cause of your problem. If you want a truly cross-browser solution and you can more easily control and handle I would suggest an external library like https://alvarotrigo.com/ which will also allow you to normally scroll if the section is bigger than 100vh, and then restart the snapping after it.